# AABB vs Circle - Vise versa using separate axis theorem

Tags: math, 3d, 2d, physics, collision

Am following this tutorial for my 2d game collision handling , this tutorial explains about the collision used in one of my favorite game "N". How they used separate axis theorem more efficiently for collision between AABB vs AABB and AABB vs Circle. http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html.  I understand the implementation of AABB vs AABB collision handling but I couldn't understand AABB vs Circle collision detection especially **voronoi regions**.Totally confused how/where to start.

**AABB vs AABB collision detection**

1. Find the axis along all the edge by finding the normal of each edge.
2. Projection all the vertices to the
   resultant Axis , final result should
   be a scalar value.
3. The resultant scalar value in turn
   is used to find whether collision is
   present or not.

Can someone please explain how to handle collision AABB vc Circle - vise versa?

Answer (score 6):

Since collisions with a circle always come down to a comparison against the radius (in your case, via projection), having the closest line segment (edge of the polygon) and the normal vector are the only building blocks you need. The normal vector is easily computed from the points of the line segment (something like unit(y2-y1, x1-x2) ... the negative reciprocal of the slope). Figuring out which edge is closest is the building block that remains. Voronoi regions give us the last building block.

You understand collisions between axis-aligned bounding boxes. I assume you also understand collisions between two circles. I'm assuming you don't understand voronoi regions. So, where to start? Voronoi diagrams. I highly suggest that you find a diagrammed explanation. [This link is quite good](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/studerende/duff/Fortune/). However, depending on how lost you are, perhaps a little additional background (seriously, though, no explanation can beat the visual):

A voronoi diagram is one of the ubiquitous data structures of computational geometry. Any computational geometry book will discuss the Voronoi diagram. It answers a simple question: where is the closest post office? Given a set of points in a plane (post offices), a voronoi diagram separates the plane into different regions, each containing one of the points. If you are in a particular region, you know which point (post office) is closest to you. If you were a circle, this would be nice for collision detection for a simple reason: the closest point is the most important one to test for collisions.

Note that if you want to mathematically derive a voronoi diagram, you simply consider all point pairs and calculate all bisecting lines. Then you intersect all of the bisecting lines and throw away the segments that are unimportant because some other point is closer to the point of interest (which happens at every intersection). This leads to a terribly inefficient algorithm, though. The efficient implementation involves another ubiquitous thing in computational geometry: the line-sweep algorithm. Its details can be found elsewhere; the important bit is that it provides a method of considering only the important points at any stage of the algorithm.

The voronoi regions in your tutorial are a little more complex. Instead of just points, we have line segments. Fortunately, the line-sweep algorithm handles this nicely. You mostly have to worry about the start or end of the line segments. Conceptually, not much changes once you have the basic algorithm down. Again, this is exceptionally helpful for collision detection with a circle: given the voronoi region, you know which line segment to test collisions against.

Does that even help? Feedback appreciated. I'll be happy to clarify anything. Explaining voronoi diagrams without visuals is probably a bad idea.

Comment: The explanation is just awesome - Yes I do have the idea of collision between two circles & AABB vs AABB, now got the glimpse of how the algorithm works and your other alternative recommendation as well.I will follow these points and going to start writing pseudo code for converting this into action. I will post my questions ASAP. Once again thank you for the comprehensive explanation.

Comment: @Anandh: "comprehensive" was my cause for concern. I couldn't provide a comprehensive explanation without diagrams, unless I spent a lot of time actually coding (code is a useful visual, don't you think?). Also, my supposition was not supposed to sound patronizing. You'd be surprised that someone can understand bounding box collisions but not the collisions of two circles (until they think about it, then the concept is usually obvious). Be patient, though. I actually figured out something at work, and may be busy for the next 6 hours. I *will* update my answer to address any questions.

Comment: Sounds good appreciated your help(helping a beginner) , I have jyst started reading this tutorial http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lineSweep if you find any tutorials for beginners please share. Thank you!

Comment: @Anandh: Are you trying to implement your own from scratch or just understand the principles? If you notice in the N tutorial, they worked out the voronoi regions for the shapes they had, and then just used the precomputed regions. No on-the-fly voronoi computation required.

Comment: @ccoakley : Exactly correct -  Actually am trying to understand the principles first before digging N Tutorial sample code. I got the idea how AABB collision was implemented in "N" and ported the same in objective C for my iphone game. Basically in N for different shapes all the significant axes are pre calculated and the same is used for creating  the world using that shape(tile) information.For few shapes especially "--= round shapes =--" I couldn't understand anything bcoz without knowing the underlying concept it's quite complicated.

Comment: @ccoakley : Any recommendation on this query?

Comment: A good tutorial? Sadly, not really. I took computational geometry from Subhash Suri at UCSB. The course was exceptional. However, his lecture notes on the subject (http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/Voronoi.pdf, http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/Intersection.pdf) don't really work without his lecture to go along. I used this book (http://www.amazon.com/Computational-Geometry-Applications-Mark-Berg/dp/3642096816) while taking the class, but I already had a grounding in the theory because of Professor Suri's lectures. It depends on how well you can learn from a textbook.

Comment: Cool , I will better buy this book and read possibly I could find the answer. Between I have come across this article http://www.sevenson.com.au/actionscript/sat/ this author discussed about collision between AABB and circle , evening am going to try this. Ill keep you updated.